# asp.net core social authentication - Is this code designed for backend also, or only for client side?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, .net-core

I have been reading today about the auth implemented in asp.net core for google and facebook, and prototype-ed a lot. Something that's not clear to me at all, even after going through the MSDN docs. and several blogs: Is any support for backend API validation added in .net core or do I still need to call into the google auth library to validate the auth tokens received from the client.

Note: I am using asp.net core as Web API and I don't use the MVC/Razor part.

thanks for any detail added on this!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. The external auth integration will take care of all things auth-related, but that's it. If you want to actually utilize the third-party API for other purposes, you're on your own there. You will actually get an access/refresh token from the third-party as a claim that you can utilize to authorize other calls, though.

Comment: For OAuth there are 8 steps that need to be implemented. There are first steps between the client and the identity provider (eg google) and the last steps between my app backend  communicating with identity provider to validate the token. And finally my app backend will emit a custom app token for the client to use. I see the first steps decumented a lot, but nothing for later steps. From this was my question, and confusing, is this asp.net core a full solution for auth? Or is it just for client side/ my first detailed steps?

Comment: That's what I'm talking about that. That part - all of it - is already handled by the built-in stuff. Except for the last part, sending your own token back to your client. You probably need to handle that bit.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. In this case where is the google identity provider backend validation (without a third party lib), I could not find it? Everything I see !n docs is about the client side w/ MVC. ( I already generate my tokens at the backend, but if I can get the backend - google provider integration for free then it would be great). What I am missing from understanding is the google provider callback and validation.

Comment: No sure what you mean. The process is the same for any form of external authentication. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-2.1 and for Google specifically: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: Sorry, I could have added an example, eg: how could I get the callback to “onpostconfirmationasync” if I don’t use Razor (as I use React and Mobile with Rest)? That what I called above identity provider callback.